# while loop with variable definition in C

Tags: c, while-loop

I'm currently trying to loop over a collection retrieved by an API in C.

The API offers a function getNext() that returns a reference to the next element in the collection, or NULL if the end has been reached.

Now i wanted to declare a variable in a while expression and loop until NULL:

```
// create collection from API
Collection collection = create();

if (collection == NULL) {
  return -1
}

while (const Element *e = getNext(collection) != NULL) {
  // print data from e
}
```

When compiling, 'error: unexpected expression' pops up. Why does that statement not work in C? How can I loop over the collection when all I have is a function getNext() that returns either an element or NULL?

I also tried the following, but the same error occured:

```
while ((const Element *e = getNext(collection)) != NULL) {
  // print data from e
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible because `while()` expects an expression and it is not possible to place a declaration in the expression (though it is possible to introduce a new type with expression!).

The best you can get is:

```
const Element *e;
while ((e = getNext(collection)) != NULL) {
  // print data from e
}
```

---

It is however possible to achieve the desired functionlity with a `for` loop.

```
for (const Element *e; (e = getNext(collection)) != NULL; ) {
  // print data from e
}
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo, good observation, there are even more bizarre tricks with `for` loop. It is even possible to emulate `if (type x = expr; x)`

Comment: You can add an *hanging block* to further limit the scope: `int e = 42; { const Element *e; while (e = getNext(collection)) { /* e is a pointer here */ } /* e is a pointer here */ } /* e is int here */`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, in contrast to a [`for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/for) statement, you cannot declare a new variable in a [`while`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/while) statement. Therefore, the following line is wrong:

```
while (const Element *e = getNext(collection) != NULL) {
```

You could fix this by writing the following:

```
const Element *e;

while ( e = getNext(collection) != NULL ) {
```

A more compact way of writing this is the following:

```
for ( const Element *e; e = getNext(collection) != NULL ; ) {
```

The second version has the advantage that the [scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/scope) of the variable `e` is limited to the `for` loop.

However, the lines mentioned above are also wrong, for the following reason:

The `!=` operator has [higher precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than `=`. So the line

```
while ( e = getNext(collection) != NULL) {
```

is equivalent to:

```
while ( e = ( getNext(collection) != NULL ) ) {
```

This is not want you want. You should write the following instead:

```
while ( ( e = getNext(collection) ) != NULL ) {
```

Comment: "_You could fix this by writing the following_" - `{ const Element *e; while(...) {} }` would be more similar to what OP wants in terms of context (I think).

Comment: @TedLyngmo: I don't understand what you are suggesting. Are you suggesting that I put it everything into an extra code block by adding `{` and `}` around everything? That is the only difference I can find between your suggested code and my code.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. It gives the variable the same (limited) context as I think OP was aiming for.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: I don't have the impression that OP is concerned with the [scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/scope) of the variable `e`. If they are indeed concerned with the scope, it would probably be best to use `for`, as shown in my answer, instead of using `while` and adding an additional code block.

Comment: The solution isn't to spam parenthesis all over but to get rid of the assignment inside the loop condition.

Comment: @Lundin: Getting rid of the assignment in the loop condition would require either an infinite loop with an explicit `break` statement, or it would require the expression `e = getNext(collection)`, to be duplicated, so that it exists once before the loop and once inside the loop. I doubt that any such solution would be cleaner than it is now.

Comment: See the for loop answer I posted. People are far too paranoid about code repetition, it isn't the end of the world to repeat the same line twice, especially not when the machine code will likely remove it. Many fixes against code repetition introduce a cure worse than the disease. Assignment inside conditions is much worse practice than code repetition.

Answer (score 0):

In C, you can't declare a variable in the condition expression of a while loop.

GCC will tell you:

```
Error: Expected expression before 'const'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write something like this, hope it can help :)

```
void main()
{
    bool running = true;
    while(running)
    {
        printf("Running while loop\n");
        running = getNext() != NULL; //Check if there is data in your collection - otherwise exit
    }
    printf("getNext() returned NULL\n");
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some rules of thumb in C programming are: "don't do really strange things" and "never do assignments inside control or loop statements". Turns out that we can follow these rules and solve all problems by using a `for` loop:

```
for(const Element* e = getNext(collection); e != NULL; e = getNext(collection))
```